# Label and text box on the same line using css

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

When creating a new asp.net mvc3 app you get the logon and register form with a label above the text field.
I want to change it so that both the label and field are on the same line and aligned

The following doesn't work

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Account Information</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.display-label, 
.editor-label 
{
      display:inline-block;
      width: 200px;    
      text-align: right;   
      margin-right: 10px;

}

.display-field, 
.editor-field 
{
    display:inline-block;
     margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I typically float my label left and the input lines up next to it. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/qXFLa/

Here's an example of how I'd rearrange your code:

```
<div class="editor">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
</div>
```

Then, for your css:

```
.editor label {
  float: left;
  width: 30px;   // just putting an example here - but give them a width to align better
  text-align: right; // this right-aligns them with the input
}

.editor input[type=text] {
  width: 80px; // just putting an example value in here to make your inputs uniform in length
  margin: 0 0 0 10px; // just some breathing room from the labels
}
```

Comment: just tried to float left and didnt work.can you show me how you would change the css mentioned in the question

Comment: show me your markup and I can create another jsfiddle if you need

Comment: The first thing I would do would be to move your label into the same parent element as your text input. What's happening when you float your label is it's floating inside a block element, which means anything that follows will flow below it. Refer to the jsfiddle in my answer to see what I mean.

Comment: by moving the label in the same parent works.How do you align the textbox so that the form does not look messy.

Comment: Give the labels a width - this puts the inputs all the same distance from the far left, aligning them. Then, depending on how you like your labels lined up, you can either leave them as is, or text-align them right.

Answer (score 15):

I'm  using this css

```
.editor-label
{   display: block;
    float: left; 
    padding: 0; 
    width: 150px;
    margin: 1em 1em 0 0;
}

.editor-field
{
    width:auto;
    margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
    overflow: auto;
    min-height: 2em;
}
```

Comment: On a similar note, I'm not seeing any display-field/display-label element in Site.css. I have created a new project using VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

Although i have not tried the accepted answer by kinakuta, it requires you to re-arrange the Visual Studio generated view; I would approach as follows, **if you don't want to re-arrange the autogenerated layout.**, i.e. to keep the format

```
<div class="editor-label" />
<div class="editor-field" />

<div class="editor-label" />
<div class="editor-field" />

etc...
```

The following CSS appears to work for me. Feel free to offer improvements. (it looks very similar to the answer by Pa0l0)

```
<style type="text/css">
    .editor-label, .display-label
    {
        clear:both;
        float:left;
        width:150px;
        margin:1em 0 0 0;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    .editor-field, .display-field
    {
        margin:1em 0 0 0;   
        min-height:1.5em;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

A few of these answers wasn't quite what I was looking for. This bit in my CSS seems to work for my needs.

```
input,
select,
textarea{
    display:inline-block !important;
}
```