# Nesting <a> element inside Html.LabelFor

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-5">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.foo)
    <a data-toggle="popover" data-content="I'm a popover!" href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></a>
</div>
```

The `<a>` element (i.e. the glyphicon popover) appears *beneath* the `label` element, but I'd like to have it placed to the *right* side of the label instead.  Is there a way to accomplish this by way of nesting the `<a>` inside of the `@Html.LabelFor`?  It'd be cool to have something like:

```
<label for="foo"> I'm the label!
    <a data-toggle="popover" data-content="I'm a popover!" href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></a>
</label>
```

If not, will I have to use positioning instead?

---

**EDIT**: I ended up taking Ramo's advice and rolling with something simple.

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-5">
    <label>
       <span> I'm a **hard-coded** LabelFor DataAnnotation! </span>
       <a data-toggle="popover" data-content="I'm a popover!" href="#">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
       </a>
    </label>
</div>
```

Still interested if there's an MVC way to get Glyphicons to cohere with `@Html.LabelFor`, but my question is more or less academic at this point.

---

**EDIT #2**: I found an even easier solution which is kind of obvious in hindsight.  This approach uses positioning (i.e. `display: inline`) to ensure that the accompanying `<a>` and `<span>` elements display on the same line.

```
<div class="col-sm-5 form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.foo, new { style = "display: inline;" })
    <a data-toggle="popover" data-content="I'm a popover!" href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a table and do something like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.foo)</td>
        <td><a data-toggle="popover" data-content="I'm a popover!" href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT:**

A quick google search brought me to this result which uses CSS to accomplish your goal [Label and text box on the same line using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437621/label-and-text-box-on-the-same-line-using-css)

**EDIT 2:**

Since you are weary of using tables you might be able to do something like this.  I have not tested the code yet, but I do believe it should give you your desired behavior.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <div class="Label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.foo)</div>
         <a data-toggle="popover" data-content="I'm a popover!" href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.Label{
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: This does produce the desired kind of layout I'm looking for, although I'm a little weary about using tables to accomplish this. I was hoping there might be a cleaner way to do this - perhaps something built into MVC.

Comment: @alex I proposed a new solution that does not use tables but rather just CSS to do the positioning.  I haven't tested the code but I think this will work.  Give it a try

Comment: The second proposed solution doesn't work, and produces different behavior than the first.  The `<a>` element is pushed underneath the '<label>` element.

Comment: @alex really i just tried it.  In your css did you put `.label` instead of `label` because I forgot a period in front of `label` in the code i posted.  I just tested it and it worked for me

Comment: @alex and now that i look again label should have a capital L in the css

Comment: Yeah, it's not working for me. http://jsfiddle.net/y1foa5Lg/  I updated my answer to reflect what I'm using right now.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go ahead with positioning. Do not take unusual choices here use everything for what is supposed to be used because otherwise you will notice unusual behavior of your code in future.

Comment: This is more suited for as a comment not an answer. You are providing little to no helpful information other than telling the person to go google some more

Comment: Ramo's advice helped the most because there doesn't appear to be any way in MVC to get the *specific* behaviour I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@{
var foo = Html.LabelFor(m => m.foo)
}

<a>@foo</a>
```

Comment: I think that this would make the entire label toggle a popover on hover, as opposed to just the glyphicon.